# Files not saving correctly on ftp in FTPClient

Tags: java, upload, ftp-client

I'm using FTPClient for uploading files on ftp server. first, I have a `TempFile` object(no matters what is this object), that have a `getBytes()` method. this method returns List of bytes:

```
List<Byte> byteList = tempFile.getBytes();
Byte[] byteObjects= new Byte[byteList.size()];
byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteList.size()];
byteObjects = byteList.toArray(byteObjects);
byteArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(byteObjects);
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
ftpClient.storeFile(file.getName()+"."+file.getExtension(), stream);
```

After executing the last line of code, a file creates successfully with expected name, but when i want to open that file, i see "The image test.jpg can not be displayed, because it contains error" in the browser. What is the problem?

Comment: Please add  more code. What kind of object is `ftpClient` how you create it ...

Comment: That kind of error occures when upload binary file like Jpeg image file in ASCII mode.　Does your "ftpClient.storeFile" set mode BINARY/ASCII according to the contents of file to be transffered.

Comment: Why, why, oh why are you converting bytes to `Byte[]` and back again to `byte[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you needs to set your ftp client to transmit as binary

```
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

As per the docs

> If the current file type is ASCII, line separators in the file are transparently converted to the NETASCII format